# how to detect device type(android, ios, web) using laravel passport api?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to find device type (e.g. android, iOS or web browser) in my laravel Passport api for save record in database, but it seems impossible to do it. Please suggest me how to find device type.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting This kinda type is a really complicated task, I would like to suggest you use [MobileDetect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) or other Laravel packages for this.

```
composer require mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib
```

include the dependency in the `composer.json` file

```
{
    "require": {
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"
    }
}
```

And the functionalities are -

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
 
// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
 
}
 
// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){
 
}
 
// Exclude tablets.
if( $detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet() ){
 
}
 
// Check for a specific platform with the help of the magic methods:
if( $detect->isiOS() ){
 
}
 
if( $detect->isAndroidOS() ){
 
}
 
// Alternative method is() for checking specific properties.
// WARNING: this method is in BETA, some keyword properties will change in the future.
$detect->is('Chrome')
$detect->is('iOS')
$detect->is('UC Browser')
// [...]
 
// Batch mode using setUserAgent():
$userAgents = array(
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Desire HD Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19',
'BlackBerry7100i/4.1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/103',
// [...]
);
foreach($userAgents as $userAgent){
 
  $detect->setUserAgent($userAgent);
  $isMobile = $detect->isMobile();
  $isTablet = $detect->isTablet();
  // Use the force however you want.
 
}
 
// Get the version() of components.
// WARNING: this method is in BETA, some keyword properties will change in the future.
$detect->version('iPad'); // 4.3 (float)
$detect->version('iPhone') // 3.1 (float)
$detect->version('Android'); // 2.1 (float)
$detect->version('Opera Mini'); // 5.0 (float)
// [...]
```

See the [documentation](http://mobiledetect.net/) to learn more.

Comment: FWIW - https://github.com/jenssegers/agent is the Laravel adaption of MobileDetect

Comment: Then using **Agent** ( https://github.com/jenssegers/agent ) would be easier as it uses the mentioned ( **mobiledetect** - https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect ) library.

Comment: Thank you very much, but It is not working with passport api but when i am trying this on web browser it is working perfect.